# How to change font-size for a single face in a single buffer

Tags: faces, fonts

I am trying to change the font size of a single face only within a single buffer.

Currently, the face is defined like this:

[image]

So I thought that all I need to do is evaluate

```
(face-remap-add-relative 'org-level-2 :height 1.0)
```

In the buffer where I want the change to be effective. However, doing that has absolutely no effect.

I then tried

```
(face-remap-add-relative 'org-level-2 :scale 1.0)
```

which did change the font size, but it also got rid of all the other text properties (i.e., text is no longer green and bold).

What do I need to do to just make the font smaller, without changing any of the other attributes?